# Globally Configure Faraday User-Agent

Tags: ruby, cas, faraday

I have inherited a Ruby project forked from CASinoApp, which depends on CASino, which uses Faraday for HTTP requests. I *really* do not want to fork CASino to modify [how it invokes `Faraday.post`](https://github.com/rbCAS/CASino/blob/master/app/models/casino/service_ticket/single_sign_out_notifier.rb#L30).

Is there a way to configure Faraday *globally* to set it's User-Agent for any-and-all requests that follow? Specifically, I *cannot* run Faraday's constructor to get a connection and configure it - because CASino would not then use my configured connection for it's requests. I need to somehow mutate Faraday's internal "default" configuration.

Comment: Just found this, will explore tomorrow and follow up here if it works: https://github.com/lostisland/faraday/blob/5ba7c30a7bb1d755c6e777b16b68ba1c498a49a7/lib/faraday.rb#L123

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In modern versions of Faraday, you should be able to use `Faraday.default_connection_options`. In our case, we were stuck using 0.9.2 and had to actually configure a connection object and set `Faraday.default_connection` for reasons [addressed](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday/pull/707/files) in [0.12.2](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday/releases/tag/v0.12.2).

```
Faraday.default_connection = Faraday.new(options = {:headers=>{:user_agent=>"My Custom UA Here"}})
```

Comment: The `options=` part is extraneous here, but that's the right idea.

Comment: Quick question, how do we apply it on rails? Perhaps creating a new initializer about it?

Answer (score 3):

For anyone specifically trying to set default timeout options like we were, this worked for us in a modern Faraday implementation:

```
Faraday.default_connection_options = Faraday::ConnectionOptions.new({timeout: 5, open_timeout: 5})
```

You could also set any other request options inside that hash.

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me in the faraday version 1.1.0.

```
Faraday.default_connection_options.headers = { "User-Agent" => 'Mozilla/5.0' }
```